# Highcharts: Disable animation for specific event

Tags: javascript, animation, events, charts, highcharts

Is there a way to temporarily disable animation throughout the chart? My chart has a load event that causes the axes of the chart to change position, and the animation for this is unnecessary. Still, I want animation throughout the chart to be active, so that if one interacts with the chart (ticks off legend items, for example), the update is animated.

I've made an example chart [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r5pyne7f/4/).

```
var chart = new Highcharts.chart({
  chart: {
    //animation: false,
    type: 'spline',
    width: 600,
    renderTo: 'chart-container',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        this.update({
          chart: { spacingBottom: 50 }
        })
      }/*,
      render: function() {
        this.update({
          chart: {
            animation: true
          }
        })
      }*/
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Title',
    align: 'left'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Subtitle',
    align: 'left'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'First series',
    data: [50,60,70,80],
    color: '#5995ae'
  }, 
    {
    name: 'Second series',
    data: [43,53,43,49],
    color: '#cf921c'
  }, 
    {
    name: 'Third series',
    data: [49,38,51,79],
    color: '#abd309'
  }]
});
```

In the example, spacingBottom is changed after the chart is loaded. This causes an animation that I want to disable (the xAxis moves upward), but I can't seem to figure out how to specifically disable the animations for axes.

The offending animation is disabled if I simply disable all animations (chart.animation = false), but this also means disabling all other animations that I want to keep.

You can see that I've attempted to add an extra event on render (currently commented out), but in practice the browser is not able to handle extra workload of both the load and the render event. Unless I'm missing something.

It would be neat if I could somehow disable all animation specifically during the load event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a solution that will work for all cases, but it does seem to work for yours.

You can tell update not to redraw by passing a false for the redraw parameter https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update.  Then you can redraw without animation by passing in a false for the animation parameter https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#redraw.

```
events: {
    load: function() {
    this.update({
        chart: { spacingBottom: 50 }
    }, false);
    this.redraw(false);
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r5pyne7f/5/

Comment: I can confirm that this works for all of the charts that I am working with so far, including line, column, and pie charts. The initial animation for columns are disabled as a consequence, but that's not a big problem. Thank you!